# Facebook Like button and likes count error

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Yes, yet another facebook like button error. Read a dozen of threads about those errors, but it wasn't helpful.

The page: http://tanios.com/vote/

The problem is that when I click like below the picture for the first time it's OK. But when I dislike it (I press 'remove & unlike' in my news feed) and try to click like again it throws an error and suggests checking using lint. But lint doesn't show any errors. If I log out of facebook and log in again then it's the same (ok for the first, but error after unliking).

The next problem is that counter near like button says that 6 people like this. But counter above the image (data taken from http://graph.facebook.com/http%3A%2F%2Ftanios.com%2Fvote%2Findex.php%3Furl%3D1 and http://graph.facebook.com/http%3A%2F%2Ftanios.com%2Fvote%2Findex.php%3Furl%3D2 respectively) shows different number.

Is there anything I can do about this or it's something temporally wrong with facebook?

I have a simple redirection:

```
$is_facebook = (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "facebook") > 0);
if($_GET["url"] == 1 && !$is_facebook) header("Location: $website#lebanon");
if($_GET["url"] == 2 && !$is_facebook) header("Location: $website#montreal");
```

But removing this doesn't change anything.

Comment: I just noticed this:https://www.facebook.com/promotions_guidelines.php  See #5.  What you are doing may be in violation since you're voting using their Like buttons.

Comment: Thanks, I think that can be the reason. Because well I have no idea what else can be wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odd, I don't get any error when unliking from either my profile page or from your website.  Here's the payload I get back for the unlike action

> for
>   (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":"requires_login":false,"error_info":null,
>   "show_error":false,"node_type":"ExternalPage",
>   "node_id":{theId},"edge_type":"ExternalPageLike","connect_text":0,"success":true,"already_connected":false,
>   "user_profile":{"name":"{myName}","profile_url":"https://www.facebook.com/{myURL}","pic_square":"{myPix"},"story_fbid":0,"is_admin":false,"admin_url":""}}

Is there something I need to try to make it break?

Comment: Can you like it again? Because for me, I can unlinke but then I can't like the same picture again. Maybe it has something to do with incorrect like counters.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The like counters work fine for me.  The only time I see bad like counters is when the page is not accessible to Facebook to lint.